# Does PHP Session start when setting a value?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

So the question is if it's possible that session in PHP is auto-starting when setting any value in it, because i read that you need to call `session_start()` and in my current code i'm not doing that anywhere so i'm not quite sure if it's really necessary. 
Some information about my environment: 
XAMPP for Linux 5.6.8 /Ubuntu 14
I'm using Codeigniter Framework 3.0.2 and PHP Version 5.6.8.
And yes, i checked php.ini file and i can't find any session.start_auto there so i'm really confused.

My login page code goes something like this:

```
        if ($this->login_model->authenticate($data))
            {
                #start session, save necessary data
                $this->load->model('user_model');

                $user = $this->user_model->get_user_by_email($data['email']);

                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->user_id;
                $_SESSION['user_email'] = $user->email;
                $_SESSION['user_authenticated'] = TRUE;

                $this->load->helper('url');

                redirect('principal');
            }
```

then in every page i call a helper method that checks if user is authenticated in this way:

```
public function user_is_authenticated()
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user_authenticated']) || !$_SESSION['user_authenticated'] === TRUE)
        {
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
```

And finally, my logout page does this:

```
 public function end_session()
    {

     if (session_destroy())
     {
        redirect('login');
     }

    }
```

The thing is that it works fine, because if i don't log in i'm not able to access pages that have that validation method. So, i never used `session_start()`. Should I? Where?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `$this->session->set_userdata()` instead.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Why? And i really can't see how your reply answers my question. I think i was specific enough.

Comment: Session Library http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: @Otroletravaladna I ll add my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Should I?**

No. You don't have to use `session_start()`.

---

**Why?**

Codeigniter use `set_userdata` method to set Session.

In [Codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#initializing-a-session)

> Sessions will typically run globally with each page load, so the Session class should either be initialized in your controller constructors, or it can be auto-loaded by the system. For the most part the session class will run unattended in the background, so simply initializing the class will cause it to read, create, and update sessions when necessary.

---

**Is there any addition thing to do??**

Yes. You have to load Session library in `autoload.php`

---

**How to use `set_userdata`?**

```
$newdata = array(
        'user_id'  => $user->user_id,
        'user_email'     => $user->email,
        'user_authenticated' => TRUE
);

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata)
```

---

**How to check session is set or not??**

```
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
if (isset($user_id)) {
    echo $name;
}
else
{
    echo "Not set";
}
```

---

**Any addition resources there??**

1. [Session Library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, i knew somewhere the magic should be happening, didn't know where!

Comment: @Otroletravaladna Welcome to Satck Family. And happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter you do not need to use session_start(). just autoload the session library in the autoload.php file inside config folder

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

for more read this tutorial

http://w3code.in/2015/10/session-handling-in-codeigniter/

Or you can use native session for native  session read this

http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-use-native-php-session-in-codeigniter/

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! That answers my question too.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like session is using cache, can you var dump the sessionid @ the top of the page and ensure that it returns empty. Also, i would try this on a incognito mode of the browser to remove the ambiguity of cachee

```
var_dump (session_id())
```

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter, no need to use `session_start()`.

Just use

```
$this->session->set_userdata();// to set the session values.
```

and

```
$this->session->userdata();// to retreive the session values.
```

Please check [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) for more info.